# Remove glassy highlight listview selected and mouse over items

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I am personalizing the style of my listview,

but there is a glassy effect I did not manage to remove...

Here is an image of my listview with empty data

[image: ugly style selected item]

The first orange element is the header, then the selected item and then a mouseover item.

I try to get everything as the header flat and mat.

Anyone knows what to do? I tryed severals things ...

**Edit : Add XAML code**

The listview :

```
<ListView Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle1}" x:Name="AffairesList" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding affaires.Affaires}" MouseDoubleClick="AffairesList_MouseDoubleClick" AlternationCount="2"  >            
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Nom" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

ListViewItemStyle1 :

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFEBEBEB"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFA200" />
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFA200"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

ListViewStyle1 (I suppose I have to modify the Themes:ListBoxChrome part) :

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBorder}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF042271"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">

                <Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Themes:ListBoxChrome>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747(v=vs.110).aspx) will help. Check out the VisualStates for ListBoxItem.  You also should focus on Control colors at the bottom.

Comment: Is there another style in effect here? If I use the style you've posted, my selected item is still blue/default.